# IMO problem 2, 2002. The circle $S$ has center $O$, and $BC$ is a diameter of $S$...

Tags: geometry, contest-math

**IMO problem # 2, 2002:** The circle $S$ has center $O$, and $BC$ is a diameter of $S$. Let $A$ be a point of $S$ such that $\measuredangle AOB<120^{\text{o}}$. Let $D$ be the midpoint of the arc $AB$ that does not contain $C$. The line through $O$, parallel to $DA$ meets the line $AC$ at $I$. The perpendicular bisector of $OA$ meets $S$ at $E$ and at $F$. Prove that $I$ is the incenter of the triangle $CEF$.

I need to draw this. I don't understand how to visualise it. Also, the incenter (same thing as the centre of gravity?) of a triangle is where the the three side bisectors meet?

Comment: No, the incenter is where the angle bisectors meet.

Comment: You should try to draw it yourself step by step based on the original statements given in the problem. The statements of IMO problems are generally very clear.

Comment: @quasi: Where did I misstate it? Yes, It's #2 I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: @LazyLee: Ok, I'll try to draw it and post it here so you can check If I've drawn it correctly.

Comment: @Parseval -- It's OK, Your wording is not exactly the same, but it's equivalent to the original. so no objection.

Comment: @quasi-- I just copied it from here: http://imomath.com/othercomp/I/Imo2002.pdf

Comment: @Parseval: Instead, you could have obtained the official version:
$$$$
$\qquad\qquad$https://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx
$$$$
The wording in your version is slightly different, but in any case, clearly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

[image]

I can recommend using [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) for this sort of illustration.

Comment: This is sick. Are all those lines really necessary? What exactly is the definition of the "in center"? Is it the same as the centre of gravity?

Comment: @Parseval: The line $AB$ and its perpendicular bisector $OD$ aren't mentioned in the problem, but were needed to find the point $D$. The line through $I$ perpendicular to $EF$ also isn't mentioned but was needed to draw the incircle at $I$. For incenter, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incenter.html). A tringle's center of gravity is the [centroid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleCentroid.html).

Answer (score 1):

$DO = AO$ so $\angle \, ADO = \angle \, DAO = \alpha$. But $AD \, || \, IO$ so $\angle \, IOA = \angle\, DAO  = \alpha$ so $\angle \, DAO = \alpha = \angle \, IOA$. Also $DO \perp AB$ and $AC \perp AB$ so $AI \, ||\, DO$ and $AD \, ||\, IO$ so $ADOI$ is a parallelogram which means that $$\angle \, OIA = \angle \, ADO = \alpha = \angle \, DAO = \angle \, IOA$$ therefore triangle $AIO$ is isosceles and thus $AO = AI$. However, since $EF$ is orthogonal bisector of radius $AO$, triangles $AEO$ and $AFO$ are equilateral so $$AE = AO = AF = AI $$ which means that the points $E, \, I, \, F$ lie on a circle centered at point $A$ of radius $AE = AI =AF$. However, since $AE = AF$ one infers that $\text{arc}(AE) = \text{arc}(AF)$ so $CA$ is the angle bisector of $\angle \, ECF$. Therefore, the fact that  $AE = AI =AF$ where $I$ is on the angle bisector of $CA$ is possible if and only if $I$ is the incenter of triangle $CEF$. Indeed, let $$\angle \, IEF = \alpha_1 \,\, \text{ and } \,\, \angle \, IEC = \alpha_2$$. As $ECFA$ is inscribed in a circle and $CA$ is the angle bisector of $\angle \, ECF$, so $$\angle \, ECI = \angle \, FCI = \gamma$$ one concludes that $$\angle \,  FEA= \angle \, FCA = \angle \, FCI = \gamma$$ because $I \in CA$. Therefore, $$\angle \, IEA = \angle \, IEF + \angle \, FEA = \alpha_1 + \gamma$$ However, $$\angle \, EIA = \angle \, IEC + \angle \, ECI = \alpha_2 + \gamma$$ By the previously proven fact that $AE = AI$ it follows that triangle $AEI$ is isosceles and thus $$\angle \, IEA = \angle \, EIA$$ This latter identity means that $$\alpha_1 + \gamma = \angle \, IEA = \angle \, EIA = \alpha_2 + \gamma$$ which after canceling out $\gamma$ from both sides of the equation yields $$ \alpha_1 = \angle \, IEF =  \angle \, IEC = \alpha_2$$ which means that $EI$ is the angle bisector of angle $\angle \, CEF$ and therefore $I$ the intersection point of the angle bisectors of triangle $CEF$, i.e. $I$ is the incenter of triangle $CEF$.